# how can get android device SN code in unity3d?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, serial-number

How can get android device SN code in unity3d ?
I try with

```
SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier.ToString()
```

I see more info but I can`t find my SN device code .

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)myActivity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uid = tManager.getDeviceId();

Mentation android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" in your manifest file

Comment: I Work with Unity3d engine and your code don`t work in Unity3d.